# Send email with FQDN including directory

Tags: c#, email

I'm trying to send email with C#. Our email provider suggested that I use `mail.example.com/exchange` instead of `mail.example.com`

```
string mailServer;
mailServer = "mail.example.com";
mailServer = "mail.example.com/exchange";

SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(mailServer);
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
smtpClient.Send("from@example.com", "to@foo.com", "subj", "email body");
```

When `mailServer` does not include a directory, after a long pause, I get:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

When `mailServer` does include a directory, with no pause at all, I get:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'mail.example.com/exchange'

How can I send an email with C# for a FQDN that includes a directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SMTP doesn't support the concept of directories, so you might want to get an email provider that knows what they're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

That seems more like a webmail address than an SMTP address. DNS isn't going to know what to do with that path. Verify that they are talking about SMTP connections (very likely they have an alternate port they use)